# Clustering algorithms with multiple unrelated features

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, dbscan

I have been watching tutorials on clustering. I understand the concept on small data sets like iris etc. What I am having trouble with is trying to cluster a data set with i.e. 20 unrelated features. For example how can I handle a situation when 5 or 6 of those features are represented in binary and the rest are numerical features? Let's say that feature 1 is 1200, feature 2 is 10, feature 3 is 1, feature 4 is 1 etc. How does an algorithm such as k-means work in that scenario? Does it cluster all the feature 1 together, feature 2 together etc. Or will it cluster all the binary features together?

Comment: IMO it doesn't make much sense to cluster __unrelated__ features...

Comment: Hi, ive been trying kmeans on a dataset from kaggle that has 30 features, physiological, environmental and vehicle based features that i can run classification algorythms like logistic regression to predict driver alertness. I guess my point was, are datasets like this suitable for clustering algorythms. If so, what would be clustered together?

Comment: I mean when you cluster together unrelated features - what does it give you? It'll put in one cluster `2 apples` and `3 pigs` and in other cluster `1200   cars` and `900 kg of something` - does it make much sense?

Comment: The objects you mentioned would never be in the one dataset. My features are in the one dataset. The features may not be related, but they can be combined to make a prediction using supervised algorithms. Im struggling to see how this dataset, or many other similar datasets can be used in an unsupervised algorythm. Which they are.

Comment: Look at the equation that kmeans optimizes. Does this make sense for your data? If not, then the result won't be useful. And I'm not convinced that summing over all features is always a good thing... because that means computing "4 wheels² + 140 miles² per hour² =" where it should be pretty obvious this is nonsense to compute. It gets easier to see when you put units on your attributes.